# PHP post through URL parameters

Tags: php, mysql, json, post, http-post

I am trying to do php post to mysql databse using a android app  and a website url.

But I do not know how to make a post request through a url.

I tried http://localhost/api/create_product.php?name=chetan&price=2000&description=someDescription

This returns required fields missing.
Maybe the url I'm trying to pass is incorrect

Help me to know that how do I do a post in DB using URL that returns JSON for success.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

DB_CONNECT() is working fine as I am able to do a GET query successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost/api/create_product.php?name=chetan&price=2000&description=someDescription  => This is a request with GET parameters and your statement here :

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
```

Are checking for POST parameters, either you change every $_POST by $_GET, either you change your method of passing arguments cause usually when you give arguments to put it in a database it's through POST and not GET for security reasons. GET parameters are used to read something but not insert.

Comment: Thank you,
Can you tell me how do I pass arguments in the URL correctly for POST

Comment: POST parameters are not given in the URL, you will need to specify that it is POST parameters in your android app.

Comment: As I said it's on the android side, where you call the url, do you have the snippet code of your app where you're making the call to show me?